# I can't access ubuntu 13.10 after installing windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot

I was using Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu Studio 13.10 along with windows 7,and then I installed windows 8.1 in place of the Windows 7. Now the PC(Toshiba Satellite L855) directly boot into windows 8.1 with out giving me the grub choice menu. I can't access both Ubuntu as well as Ubuntu Studio OS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest option for you is to click this link and try out Boot Repair to detect and write a new Grub bootloader which will let you boot into ubuntu and windows again...

[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Hay I couldn't boot the Boot Repair...it keeps saying no os found

Comment: Try the 2nd option from the link, boot using the Ubuntu CD or Flash Drive you used to install with, then install boot repair on the live session and use from there...